# Unable to use a new SparkSession after stopping the previous one

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I created a SparkSession (with enabledHiveSupport()) and running locally.
I want to execute a set of sql's in one SparkSession, stop it and start another.

But when I stop a SparkSession and get a new one using the SparkSession.builder(), I get a new SparkSession object but the sql fails with "Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database.."

Since we can have one only one SparkContext per JVM, does this mean I cannot getOrCreate SparkSession, stop it and repeat?

Is there any way to execute a set of sql's in a new session every time? (I know there is SparkSession.newSession, though I can't stop that session too as the underlying shared SparkContext will stop, right?)

Comment: Why can't you keep the session open?

Comment: I am going beyond the heap space since I am doing repetitive operations on different data partitions. I do not have enough experience to say that it is the main reason but I think some old dataframes fills the heap space in the session. Hence, I want to clear the session.

Answer (score 3):

Hi you can go with SparkSession.newSession cause as per official documentation

***SparkSession:***
Start a new session with isolated SQL configurations, temporary tables, registered functions are isolated, but sharing the underlying SparkContext and cached data.

```
Note
    Other than the SparkContext,all shared state is initialized lazily. This method will 
    force the initialization of the shared state to ensure that parent and child sessions 
    are set up with the same shared state. If the underlying catalog implementation is 
    Hive, this will initialize the metastore, which may take some time.
```

a sample code how you can use multiple spark session

```
object WorkimngWithNewSession {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // creating a new session
    val spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("understanding session")
                .master("local[*]")
                .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._
    val df = Seq("name","apple").toDF()

    df.createOrReplaceTempView("testTable") // do not call this in case of multiple spark session and if u are using this view in all of them.
    df.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView("testTable") // call this for multiple spark session

    spark.sql("SELECT * FROM testTable").show()
    // spark.stop()  // do not call this as it will stop sparkContext

    val newSpark = spark.newSession()
    newSpark.sql("SELECT * FROM global_temp.testTable").show() // call global view by using global_temp


    spark.stop() // if u want u can call this line in the end to close all spark session
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this looks feasible. But I want to understand why on creating a new SparkSession (verified that the previous SparkSession.sparkContext is stopped) and the new SparkSession.sparkContext is active.
Since I have only 1 active SparkContext in JVM at any time, why does the error still show up?

Comment: @Punsh I think closing sparkSession closes sparkContext also. which I don't like either.